# What are NVMe namespaces

Tags: ssd, uefi, nvme

Reading up on NVMe I encountered concept of namespaces. From what I gather they seems to be roughly non-resizable logical volumes implemented in hardware but they are nowhere really explained.

(Bonus question - how do they interact with EFI boot)

Comment: There's more in-depth information on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520231/what-are-nvme-namespaces-how-do-they-work ...

Answer (score 1):

A namespace defines a contiguously-addressed range of Non- Volatile Memory similar to a SCSI Logical Unit (LUN) or a NVM Express    namespace. Namespaces described by this specification can be either Persistent Memory namespaces or Block Mode namespaces.
For more information you should probably check this document. 
http://pmem.io/documents/NVDIMM_Namespace_Spec.pdf